# Use of Session in our WCF Service for the model makes the Communicator service hang

Tags: 2011, wcf, extension-model

We're in the process of building a extension.

This extension has a Editor and a Model. In the Model we have a
   service defined that acts as a Proxy to a external service. Doing all
   the XML formatting & Authentication to use the data in Tridion
   Controls.

This is working fine. But a few days a ago we hit a speed bump.

When you entered the Tridion Content Manager everything would load
   fine. Then if you were to hit refresh the Skeleton of the Content
   Manager would load but all calls to the communicator would hang. And
   after a few minutes would just start working fine.

We initially though this was some timeout of a thread and the
   communicator was having a Deadlock and the thread was timing out.
   Another cause mentioned, was that we were not closing the WCF
   connection correctly. This was checked and traced. And we were indeed
   closing our methods.

After a few days debugging we found that the cause was  the Session
   from System.Web.HTTPContext.Current.Session (***off the top of my head, excuse if it's wrong***) that would simply hang.
   We removed the references to the session and everything started
   working correctly with no hanging.

We were using the session to save a authentication token from the
   service in. This just meant we didn't need to authenticate with every
   request.

**We did check and the WCF service is marked as ASPNet Compatible. The strange part is that it works the first time ??**

Why would this be ? Any ideas ?

Comment: You may want to consider asking this question in Stack Overflow too... (wider .NET audience)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no session first time in to the session 
Is the session actually being created

May be think about the security context that creates the session and the browser

Comment: Interesting. But how would I test this ?

Comment: As i understand it the asp.net session state service needs to be running on the server that could be your first check and IIS has a module that needs to be enabled. Have you tried retrieving the session state variable value immediately after setting it or debugging and inspecting the value?

Comment: Found out what was wrong. The first call to the service is done via the browser where subsequent calls are coming from the communicator service itself for which there is no service context. We ended up just doing the authenticate the entire time as it had minimal performance impact. I'm accepting your answers as this seems to be the logical route to follow if you were having the problem.